# Display multivalued polynominal values in separate rows by rapidminer

Tags: data-mining, rapidminer

In rapidminer, I have a polynominal attribute that have “Drama”, "Comedy" and “Romance” values, but some rows are multivalued, for example “Drama, Romance”, is a way that I can display such values in separate rows?

I tried split operator, but it displays values in separate attributes, but I want to display such values In separate rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think what you want to do is first use a Split operator get seperate attributes. the table would be like:

```
word_1, word_2, word_3...
Drama, Romance, 
Comedy, Romance
```

..

Afterwards you can use a Depivot on word_\d+ to put these in individual examples. Attached is a process showing this.

Best,
Martin

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><process version="7.5.003">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="7.5.003" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="7.5.003" expanded="true" height="68" name="Generate Data by User Specification" width="90" x="45" y="85">
        <list key="attribute_values">
          <parameter key="word" value="&quot;Drama, Romance&quot;"/>
        </list>
        <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="7.5.003" expanded="true" height="68" name="Generate Data by User Specification (2)" width="90" x="45" y="187">
        <list key="attribute_values">
          <parameter key="word" value="&quot;Comedy, Thriller&quot;"/>
        </list>
        <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="append" compatibility="7.5.003" expanded="true" height="103" name="Append" width="90" x="179" y="85"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="split" compatibility="7.5.003" expanded="true" height="82" name="Split" width="90" x="447" y="85"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="de_pivot" compatibility="7.5.003" expanded="true" height="82" name="De-Pivot" width="90" x="648" y="85">
        <list key="attribute_name">
          <parameter key="word" value="word_\d+"/>
        </list>
        <parameter key="index_attribute" value="id"/>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification" from_port="output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification (2)" from_port="output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 2"/>
      <connect from_op="Append" from_port="merged set" to_op="Split" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Split" from_port="example set output" to_op="De-Pivot" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="De-Pivot" from_port="example set output" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the *Nominal to Binominal* Operator to create new columns for each separate value.

Best,

David

Comment: As i said, "I want to display each separate value In separate row", currently i can display each value in separate attribute (column) by using split operator.